# Function.Function of Java 8 with multiple parameters

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I read many examples about how to easily define a lambda in Java 8. This lambda takes always one parameter like `f1`:

```
Function<Integer,Integer> f1 = (x) -> Math.pow(x,2);
```

Of course, you can extend the body like `f2`:

```
Function<Integer,Integer> f2 = (x) -> {if (x < 0)  return 0;
                                       else return Math.pow(x,2);};
```

But I cannot find a way to define a lambda with a variable number of paramters like `f3`:

```
Function<Integer,Integer,Integer> f3 = (x,y) -> {return x + y};
```

or without parameter like `f4`:

```
Function<Double> f4 = () -> {return Math.random()};
```

I am almost sure that you can define own functional interface (i.e., create a new file commonly) to develop `f3` and `f4`, but Is there some way to easily define them?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
Function<Integer,Integer,Integer> f3 = (x,y) -> {return x + y};
```

is actually a `BiFunction<Integer,Integer,Integer>`

and

```
Function<Double> f4 = () -> {return Math.random()};
```

is a `Supplier<Double>`

If you need *more* create your own, like `TriFunction<Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer>` for example

Comment: Or, if all parameters are the same type, create a varargs version: `interface NAryFunction<T, R> { R apply(T... t); }`

Comment: @Andreas I did not suggest that on purpose, I haven't found myself in a need of one, ever, so was not sure. thank you though

Answer (score 8):

> I am almost sure that you can define own functional interface (i.e.,
>   create a new file commonly) to develop f3 and f4, but Is there some
>   way to easily define them?

In addition to the Eugene answer, I would add that :

```
Function<Integer,Integer,Integer> f3 = (x,y) -> {return x + y};
```

may be considered as `BiFunction<Integer,Integer,Integer>` or simply `BinaryOperator<Integer>`. 
Note that you perform arithmetical computations with the `Integer`s in the lambda body. These produce unboxing and boxing operations : `Integer->int->Integer`. So in this use case you are encouraged to use a specialized functional interface that prevents that : `IntBinaryOperator` which the functional signature is `(int, int)-> int` that is itself a specialization of `BinaryOperator<T>` a subclass of  `BiFunction<T,T,T>`

In the same logic of sparing autoboxing operations :
 `Function<Integer,Integer> f2` should be `IntFunction f2` 
and `Supplier<Double> f4` should be `DoubleSupplier f4`.

Note also that specifying a specific number of argument makes sense as it is straight usable in a lambda body but specifying something like a var-args is possible but generally harder to exploit.

For example you could declare this interface :

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface VargsFunction<T,R> {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    R apply(T...  t);
}
```

But harder to use without delegating to a method that accepts a var-args :

```
VargsFunction<Integer, Integer> f = varg-> call(varg);

Integer call(Integer... varg) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A function that takes two arguments is a [BiFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html):

```
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> f3 = (x, y) -> x + y;
```

A function that takes no arguments is a [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html):

```
Supplier<Double> f4 = () -> Math.random();
```

or equivalently:

```
Supplier<Double> f4 = Math::random;
```